# Is migrating data from Magento 2 store to a different Magento 2 store using Export/Import within Admin panel even possible? How to complete the job?

Tags: migrate

```
from Magento 2.4.2-p1
to Magento 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
Amasty extensions
```

We have to abandon our Magento 2.4.2-p1 store because there are just way too many problems and *I'm tired of trying to fix it*.

My idea was to make a fresh Magento 2.4.5-p1 install and transfer everything using the Export/Import feature in Magento 2 Admin panel PLUS use an external extension such as Magento 2 'Order Import Export' by Meetanshi ( https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-order-import-export.html ) to move orders over.

I set up the websites/stores/storefronts manually and did more-less successfully transfer products and categories over and I cleaned that up. I think I have exported and imported these 2 as well:

```
- Customers Main file
- Customer Addresses
```

And I was looking at external 3rd part extensions such as Magento 2 'Order Import Export' by Meetanshi ( https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-order-import-export.html ) to export and import Orders.

I have these questions about this process:

- **If I do this, will it all link together?** Meaning - *when the customer logs into their account, will they see their previous orders and all of their saved addresses etc.?*
- *I understand there is a problem transferring passwords from Magento 1 to Magento 2* regarding how the passwords are encoded but does this issue also occur when transferring customers from Magento 2.4.2-p1 to Magento 2.4.5-p1? I tried to log into my test customer account that I transferred from Magento 2.4.2-p1 into Magento 2.4.5-p1 and my password does NOT work. Furthermore, the Reset password does not send an Email to reset password either from front or back-end! Why is that and how to fix it so that:
- **the old passwords work**
- the password reset link generates and sends an Email out

---

**UPDATED on June 3rd, 2023:**

Someone suggested the "Improved Import & Export for Magento 2" extension by Firebear studio:

https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html

I have contacted them asking whether their extension would do this and their reply suggests I may be able to do this without the extension:

*You can use our extension to export the data from one magento store and import from another.
However, since you want to migrate data from 2.4.x to 2.4.x we recommend you to just upgrade the database or move appropriate data tables from one db to another.*

I cannot just upgrade the database because it really is broke beyond repair = including the fact that I purchased the multi-step checkout from Webkul and they were able to install it on the Magento 2.4.5-p1 instance I'm building but NOT on the Magento 2.4.2-p1 instance.

**How can I move the appropriate data tables from one database to the other? I feel I'm so close yet not able to complete the mission. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!**

Further to all of this, doing the Addresses export on the old Magento 2.4.2-p1 does not work:

```
- System - Export - Entity type = Customer addresses
```

It gives the following Error:

```
Please correct the data sent value.
```

To summarise then:

1. How can I fix the passwords so that customers can log in with the same password they created on our Magento 2.4.2-p1 instance?
2. Why is the password reset feature not working and how to fix that?
3. What are my best options to get orders moved over and have the customers, customer addresses etc. all working as expected?
4. How to fix the 'Customer addresses' export not working on the Magento 2.4.2-p1 instance?

---

Update to answer post by @GerranoMargeno

**1.** When I go to:

- Stores - Settings - Configuration - CUSTOMERS - Customer configuration - Password Options

I do not have "Password Hashing Algorithm" as one of the options:

[image]

**2.** I don't think I have a problem sending Emails - the Order Confirmation Emails get sent out and delivered without any issues. What process does this follow? Does it need to be especially included in the cron jobs or how can I check/test/fix this?

**3.** I'm really sorry - I don't understand this. I am not trying to delete anything! I just want to move orders from Magento 2.4.2-p1 to Magento 2.4.5-p1. I'm leaning more and more towards the "Improved Import & Export for Magento 2" extension by Firebear studio. Are we confident this will do the job well?

**4.** Which logs can I pull? Would deleting all log files, then attempting to Export addresses, then pulling the newly created logs and posting that here work?

---

UPDATED:

I deleted all log files and then tried to do Export - Customer Addresses several times and here are some Errors from the log files:

**debug.log:**

```
main.DEBUG: URI '/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuNTI4MGZsb3dlcnMuY29tL2dpZnQtYmFza2V0cy0xL3dpbmUtYW5kLWJlZXItYmFza2V0cy90aGUtZmluZS1mcmVuY2htYW4tYmFndWV0dGUtc2FuZHdpY2gtYmFza2V0LTEuaHRtbA,,/product/3290/about-us'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add) [] []
[2023-06-05 21:43:28] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []


 main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 at /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []


URI '/index.php/wishlist/index/add/product/2133/form_key/xkaZ6UiGyvg0pvNq'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add) [] []
[2023-06-05 21:43:56] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []


main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "sidebar.additional" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
[2023-06-05 21:44:43] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 at /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_1"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_2"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_3"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_4"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_5"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_1"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_2"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_3"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_4"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:03] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_customer_grid_flat_5"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:04] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_catalog_category_flat_store_1_tmp_1"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:04] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_mget_catalog_category_flat_store_1_tmp_2"}} []



main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_c"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2023-06-05 21:45:05] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 950000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 4294967296 bytes. [] []
[2023-06-05 21:45:05] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 950000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 4294967296 bytes. [] []
[2023-06-05 21:45:05] main.DEBUG: URI '/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuNTI4MGZsb3dlcnMuY29tL2NhdGFsb2dzZWFyY2gvcmVzdWx0L2luZGV4Lz9wPTMxJnE9ZSUyQnNhYm9uZyUyQnBoaWxpcHBpbmVzJTJCb25saW5lJTJCY2hlY2staW4lMkMlMkIlRTIlOUUlQTElRUYlQjglOEZnMTg4LnBoJUUyJUFDJTg1JUVGJUI4JThGJTJDJTJCZnJlZSUyQnNsb3RzJTJCd2l0aCUyQmJvbnVzZXMlMkJnY2FzaCUyQmhlbHAlMkJ0aWNrZXQlMkMlMkJmcmVlJTJCc2xvdHMlMkJ3aXRoJTJCYm9udXMlMkJubyUyQmRvd25sb2FkJTJC/product/1722/about-us'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add) [] []
[2023-06-05 21:45:05] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []


 main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 950000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 4294967296 bytes. [] []
```

**Exception.log:**

```
[2023-06-05 21:43:42] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Export/Address.php on line 263 at /home/MAINWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

**System.log:**

```
[2023-06-05 21:45:05] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 950000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 4294967296 bytes. [] []
```

---

---

**UPDATED** again on June 5th, 2023:

Right, so I made a mistake. The customer file actually comes from Magento 1.9.3 hence that's why the passwords don't work? (different hash encryption methods?) **What is the easiest way to make the customer passwords from Magento 1.9.3 work on Magento 2.4.5?**

*The other issues are still not resolved.*

Answer (score 0):

Going from 2.4.2 to 2.4.5 is a big step into the void, I advise against it. I will try to help you by answering your questions.

1  Admin Panel-> Store ->Configuration ->Customer Configuration->Password option Set the "Password Hashing Algorithm" to "SHA-256".

2 The second point doesn't work why? Do you have problems sending emails? Provide more info.

3 By default magento 2 does not allow to move orders or at least not on opensource magento 2 you would need a module, but if you intend to migrate directly to the same application the information will remain not deleted.

4 if you're having problems with customer addresses it could be multiple reasons without an error log it's hard to know what the reason is.
It is certainly a default service of magento 2 so unless you have made changes directly to the vendor, the reason can be attributed to a conflict, or permissions or corrupted data in the database. You must give me more detailed information.

Comment: Hi Gerrano - thank you for your willingness to help - it is much appreciated! I have posted answers to your post to the bottom of my original post if you would please take a look? Thank you.

Comment: I'm really sorry - I made a mistake regarding the passwords = they actually come from a customer Export out of Magento 1.9.3. I've updated my post above.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue in the past.
So the solution is customer import time sent reset email to the customer below I have shared how can I achieve this.

**1) Create the registration.php file.**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**2) Create the module.xml file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName">
    </module>
</config>
```

**3) Create the di.xml file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import">
        <plugin name="send_forgot_password_email_test" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Import" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**4) Create the Import.php file.**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import as ImportModel;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement;

class Import
{
    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $accountManagement;

    /**
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
    ) {
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    }

    /**
     * @param ImportModel $import
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function afterImportSource(ImportModel $import, $result)
    {
        if ($import->getDataSourceModel()->getEntityTypeCode() == 'customer' &&
            $import->getDataSourceModel()->getBehavior() == 'add_update'){
            if ($_FILES['import_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name'];
                $file = fopen($tmp_name, 'r');
                $header = fgetcsv($file);
                $values = [];
                while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
                    if (isset($row[0])) {
                        $values[] = $row[0];
                    }
                }
                fclose($file);
                if (count($values)) {
                    foreach ($values as $emails) {
                        $this->accountManagement->initiatePasswordReset($emails, AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**While you import the customer you can follow csv file like below**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm not sure if understand what to do with those files? Where do I upload them into and how do I trigger the process? If you would please give me step-by-step - it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to follow some steps for importing this file in Magento backend below I've defined steps.

Comment: - Goto admin panel click System->import->Select entity type "Customer Main" FIle and select  Import behavior "add/update complex data". Then after upload the csv file and click the Check Data button after successfully check data you can import customer.